# iframe and object tag NOT working

Tags: css, html

```
    <div class="row">
        <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <object data="https://www.facebook.com" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
    </div>
```

I want to include facebook page in my website but both iframe and object tags are NOT Working.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook have security against iframes.

You can't do that. I suggest you to use their dev tools if you what to show or do something.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely run into problems linking to secure content(https) from an unsecure connection, especially with iframes i.e http://www.tinywebgallery.com/blog/iframe-do-not-mix-http-and-https

and especially with a organisation like Facebook who want to monitor usage of Facebook content to protect their brand.

But there are other ways to embedded facebook content in your website:

You can use the Facebook Embedded posts widget: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts

The Facebook Page Widget: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

And then some jquery plugins which allow you to customize the look and feel:
http://pavelk2.github.io/social-feed/ and http://ironlasso.com/jqueryfacebookwall-plugin/